# Active Record model not recognizing method in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is very simple question. I was watching a railscast where a method was defined in a model  as:

```
def self.nameoffunction
   ...
end
```

Then he was able to reference the method with Model.nameoffunction in his view.

It was a railscast from 2010, so I'm guessing something has changed since then because when I try to create a function in my model I get undefined method when I try to reference it in the view.

I was hoping to create a method in my Model along the lines of:

```
def blahblah(variable)
    a = select('column').where('...variable referenced here...').limit(2) 
    b = []
    b.push(a[0]['column'])
    b.push(a[1]['column'])
    return b.sum
end
```

When I go into my console and type `Model.blahblah` I get undefined error.

So my question is when can I use the method from `Model.blahblah` and when do I have to create an object such as `Model.find_by_id(3)` before I can use the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `self.` so it's a class method rather than an instance method like the one you currently have.

```
def self.blahblah(variable)
    a = select('column').where('...variable referenced here...').limit(2) 
    b = []
    b.push(a[0]['column'])
    b.push(a[1]['column'])
    return b.sum
end
```

Another option is to do the following:

```
class << self
  def blahblah(variable)
    a = select('column').where('...variable referenced here...').limit(2) 
    b = []
    b.push(a[0]['column'])
    b.push(a[1]['column'])
    return b.sum
  end
end
```

Comment: try to reload the console by typing reload!

Comment: TY you were correct. I had no idea you had to reload consoles! I tested self.blahblah a million times and never thought my console was the problem.

Comment: Glad I was able to help Chowza :)